# Remove just one fragment from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Is it possible to remove a single Fragment at a position from a ViewPager without causing the whole ViewPager to redraw, i.e., destroy only 1 fragment without destroying the others in the ViewPager?
Using the example code on this page: [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html), calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after decrementing NUM_ITEMS, causes all Fragments to get destroyed and drawn again except the last due to overriding `getItemPosition()` to `return POSITION_NONE`. How can this be avoided?

Comment: can you be more clear? whats stopping from adding more fragments at the runtime to the viewpager?

Comment: I don't want the remaining fragments to get destroyed as they are performing their specific tasks, which I lose track of, when they get destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Use activityfragment from support jar and using getFragmentManager API, manually add remove fragments at the runtime. 
Only issue here is you will have to keep track of each of the fragment references.

Comment: Can you please provide sample code on how to do it in another answer. I'm new to Fragments and ViewPager. Sample code would be quite helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I am using the support library, I used the following code `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment(); fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.pager, fragment); fragmentTransaction.commit();` in onCreate of FragmentActivity, but it doesn't work, I see no fragment in the viewPager. What am I doing wrong?